# Python 2.6 How can I reiterate over a DictReader object that took in a list object?

Tags: python, list, csv

Python 2.6(necessary for the job)

```
import csv

list = ['apple,whiskey,turtle', 'orange,gin,wolf', 'banana,vodka,sparrow']
fieldNames = ['Fruit', 'Spirit', 'Animal']
reader = csv.DictReader(list,fieldnames= fieldNames)

for row in reader:
    print row['Fruit']

for row in reader:
    print row['Fruit']
```

I have some code that generates a uniform list of items per row, making a list object.  For ease of use I used the csv module's DictReader to step through the rows and do any calculations I need to but when I try to iterate a second time, I get no output.  I suspect the end of the list is being treated like an EOF but I am unable to 'seek' to the beginning of the list to do the iteration again.

Any suggestions on what I can do?  Perhaps there is a better way than using the CSV, it just seemed really convenient.

**New Code**

```
import csv

list = ['apple,"whiskey,rum",turtle', 'orange,gin,wolf', 'banana,vodka,sparrow']
processed = []
fieldNames = ['Fruit', 'Spirit', 'Animal']
reader = csv.DictReader(list,fieldnames= fieldNames, quoatechar = '"')

for row in reader:
    processed.append(row)
    print row

for row in processed:
    print row['Fruit']

for row in processed:
    print row['Spirit']
```

@jonrsharpe suggested placing the rows of reader into a list.  It works perfectly for what I had in mind.  Thank you everyone.

Comment: The `DictReader` is designed to iterate over the file rather than store it all in one go; put it in a list to "save" it.

Comment: @jonrsharpe It is already in a list but I was using the DictReader to try and work with the data as I would if I had loaded it as a csv file.  It works well for a single pass but was curious about being able to do a second pass.  With a csv, I could set the file back to the beginning with file.seek(0) and then reiterate again.  Wondering if I could get that functionality with a list in a DictReader.

Comment: No, I mean store the dictionaries produced by the `DictReader` in a list.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Oh I see what you mean.  Clever and works like a charm.  Thank you!

Comment: No problem. `csv` is build to handle arbitrarily-large files, so is based on iterators and avoids loading everything into memory unless coerced with e.g. `list(...)`. .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're indeed correct that iterating over the rows once is what the `DictReader` provides. So your options are:

- Create a new `DictReader` and iterate again (seems wasteful)
- Iterate over the rows once and perform all computations that you want to perform
- Iterate over the rows once, store the data in another data structure and iterate over that data structure as many times as you wish.

Also, if you have only the list and the field names you don't need a `DictReader` to do the same thing. If you know the data is relatively straightforward (no comma's inside the data for example and all the same number of items) then you can simply do:

```
merged = [zip(fieldnames, row.split(",")) for row in my_list]
print merged
```

Comment: Not just ``DictReader``, but python iterators in general (note; `iterator != iteratable`). The protocol is *one-way* vs. *random-access*.

Comment: That is nifty.  I'm new to Python so this is good information but unfortunately there are times I've seen commas in the field values.  That is why the 'DictReader' would be useful for me since I can specify the 'quotechar' to ignore when those commas are present in the fields.